# Can I create this XML file using

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to generate this xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<portlet-preferences>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="SharedPreferencesPortlet" user="*">
    <preference name="serverinvoketimeout" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="360"/>
    <preference name="followchanges" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="false"/>
</portlet-preference>
```

is use the folowing script:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

E = ElementMaker()

format = E.portletpreference(
    E.preference(value="360", isMultivalued="false", isModifiable="true", description="The description", name="serverinvoketimeout"),
    E.preference(value="false", isMultivalued="false", isModifiable="true", description="The description", name="followchanges"),

    user="*",

    definitionLabel="SharedPreferencesPortlet"
    )
    root = E.portletpreferences(
             format,

    )

print(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True))
```

result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<portletpreferences>
  <portletpreference definitionLabel="SharedPreferencesPortlet" user="*">
    <preference isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false"
name="serverinvoketimeout" value="360" description="The description"/>
    <preference isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false"
name="followchanges" value="false" description="The description"/>
  </portletpreference>
</portletpreferences>
```

QUESTIONS:

Is lxml suitable for this case?
How can get the right order?
example:`<preference name="serverinvoketimeout" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="360"/>`

How can get the minussign in the element name?
example:

```
<portlet-preferences>
```

Comment: The attributes order is not really important for XML documents. I do not see any problem in your result. However, your expected output is invalid : a closing tag is missing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is lxml suitable for this case? How can get the right order? example:

```
<preference name="serverinvoketimeout" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="360"/>
```

> How can get the minussign in the element name? example:

```
<portlet-preferences>
```

As the commenter mentions, ordering in attributes shouldn't matter. For the second question, `ElementMaker` instance takes a string for construction, so:

```
In [12]: f = E('portlet-preference', E.preference(value="360", isMultivalued="false", isModifiable="true", description="The description", name="serverinvoketimeout"),
    ...:                             E.preference(value="false", isMultivalued="false", isModifiable="true", description="The description", name="followchanges"),
    ...:       user="*",
    ...:       definitionLabel="SharedPreferencesPortlet")

In [22]: print(etree.tostring(f, encoding=str, pretty_print=True))

<portlet-preference user="*" definitionLabel="SharedPreferencesPortlet">
  <preference value="360" isMultivalued="false" isModifiable="true" description="The description" name="serverinvoketimeout"/>
  <preference value="false" isMultivalued="false" isModifiable="true" description="The description" name="followchanges"/>
</portlet-preference>



In [14]: root = E('portlet-preferences', f)

In [15]: print(etree.tostring(root, encoding=str, pretty_print=True))

<portlet-preferences>
  <portlet-preference user="*" definitionLabel="SharedPreferencesPortlet">
    <preference value="360" isMultivalued="false" isModifiable="true" description="The description" name="serverinvoketimeout"/>
    <preference value="false" isMultivalued="false" isModifiable="true" description="The description" name="followchanges"/>
  </portlet-preference>
</portlet-preferences>
```

Comment: i got the folowing message:     print(etree.tostring(root, encoding=str, pretty_print=True))
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2608, in lxml.etree.tostring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:48877)
TypeError: descriptor 'upper' of 'str' object needs an argument

Comment: solution: turned: print(etree.tostring(root, encoding=str, pretty_print=True))
into: print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True))